# Как получить часть документа в mongodb?

Tags: c#, mongodb

По умолчанию выборка содержит все поля документа, но мне не нужны все поля.
Например, имеется коллекция users вида:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "594706879b66306d4152039"
  },
  "userId": 123456,
  "firstName": "Anatoly",
  "lastName": "Mikhailyuk"
}
```

Нужно получить только имя пользователя с userId.
Пытался получить его так:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://user:pass@server");
var db = client.GetDatabase("collection_name");
var collection = db.GetCollection<User>("users");
var filterBuilder = Builders<User>.Filter;
var filter = filterBuilder.Eq("userId", 123456);
var result = collection.Find(filter, {"_id": 0, "userId": 0, "firstName": 1, "lastName": 0})
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Не сработало. Использовал VS2017 и MongoDB.driver версии 2.4.4.
Есть ли способ сделать это?

Comment: А что значит не сработало? Вернулись все поля? И версия базы mongodb какая? Вообще возможность вытаскивать часть полей в монге уже достаточно давно

Comment: Вам надо создать объект класса Projection, и присоединить его к фильтру http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/driver/definitions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался.

```
class User
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("userId")]
    [Required]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class UserLastName
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("lastName")]
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
}


var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://user:pass@server");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("collection");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<User>("users");
        var projection = Builders<User>.Projection.Include("lastName");
        var result = collection.Find(o => o.UserId == userId).Project<UserLastName>(projection).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(result[0].LastName);
```

Использовал VS2017 и MongoDB.driver версии 2.4.4.